# Why does the 'open file' dialog contain an 'options' button on some devices but not others?

Tags: google-chrome, big-sur, monterey, dialog

I‘m using

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
```

(run it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jmayer/pen/PoJvYLm) to test it).

in my web page to allow the user to select an image file.

In the first picture you can see the options button is the lower left corner.

In the second picture you can see the options available after clicking the options button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The options button for the open file dialog is confirmed visible on mac devices with the following specs

```
Mac(Big Sur / 11.6.1): Chrome(96.0.4664.93)
Mac(Monterey / 12.0.1): Chrome(97.0.4692.71)
```

It is confirmed not visible on a mac device with the following spec

```
Mac(Big Sur / 11.6), Chrome(Version 97.0.4692.71)
```

Without more specs the absence of an options button has been confirmed on one more mac device, and the presence of the options button has been confirmed on an additional mac device.

Any insight into why this options button seems inconsistent across mac devices when using Chrome? We discovered this inconsistency when testing an html form with a file input.

Thanks

Comment: There are no picture in the question you link to, and browsing through all the answers to maybe find the pictures you are referring to isn‘t all that useful. Please add screenshots relevant to the question here directly into your post.

Comment: Also, did you test with other applications as well to see whether this is related to Chrome or to macOS in general?

Comment: > "did you test with other applications"

Yes it's specific to Chrome. Safari doesn't have this issue.

> "Please add screenshots relevant"

I will thanks

Comment: @nohillside picture added 

Comment: And what are the options?

Comment: @benwiggy I've added pictures, the options are "Custom Files" and "All Files"

Comment: Hmm. And that's the standard Chrome Open file dialog? I would have expected "HTML files", "Image files" etc -- file types that can be opened. TBH, I'd ask Chrome support.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! The accept attribute of an html input is set to "img/*", and this is the Chrome Open file dialog as a result, for some macs but not others. I have dark mode settings on obviously in the screenshots above

Comment: If this open dialog is triggered from HTML can you add a *minimal* HTML source which triggers it? This would allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the delay. https://codepen.io/jmayer/pen/PoJvYLm

Comment: This isn‘t a minimal HTML snippet so you need to help with further analysis: if you open the same page in Safari or Firefox, does it work as expected?

Comment: Sorry, at this point I don't find your help very helpful. Thanks anyways though

Comment: Without a minimal HTML source allowing the reproduction of the problem nobody here can (or will) check whether the same issue happens for them (with the same or different versions of Chrome and/or of macOS, or with different browers). So the best guess currently is "this seems to be a bug in Chrome which needs to be reported to Google/the Chrome dev team".

Comment: Codepen (linked above) is a common way to reproduce bugs in the web development community, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the patience, I didn't realised that at first. Learned something out of this.